Drupal hook update issue
I am working on Drupal 10. I need to update the status field to "TRUE" for the existing content type nodes. I have used hook_update to update 700 nodes… But once the hook_update runs, it is updating the first 250 nodes alone… Again i run the hook update, the next 100 nodes are updates. in single execution, nodes are not updated.

Can we see your hook_update function?

hook_update is not made for this kind of jobs
Definitely using hook_update is not the right way for this kind of job. As mentioned in the docs:

In particular, loading, saving, or performing any other CRUD operation on an entity is never safe to do (they always involve hooks and services).

What I suggest here is to create a hook_cron instead. My suggestion is:
/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 * Changes field to TRUE
 */
function MODULE_NAME_cron()
{
  /**
   * Query the entities to fetch.
   * You can set the conditions as you prefer (Default: 'status' = FALSE)
   *
   * Maybe you can set up the limit in a Settings form (Default: 50)
   */
  $config = \Drupal::config('MODULE_NAME.settings');
  $max_entities = $config->get("MODULE_NAME.max_entities") ?? 50;
  $ids = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('ENTITY_TYPE')->getQuery()
    ->accessCheck(FALSE)
    ->condition('status', FALSE)
    ->range(0, $max_entities)
    ->execute();

  /** No Entities found */
  if (!count($ids)) {
    \Drupal::logger("MODULE_NAME.cron")->notice("No Entities found to update.");
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Process every Entity with status = FALSE
   * Set status to TRUE
   * 
   * ENTITY_TYPE::
   * Refers to the Entity Type class. For example:
   * \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::
   */
  $entities = ENTITY_TYPE::loadMultiple($ids);
  foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    /**
     * Work on your $entity here :).
     * Don't forget to ->save() the entity.
     */
    $entity->set('status', TRUE)->save();
  }
  \Drupal::logger("MODULE_NAME.cron")->notice("Entities updated: " . count($ids));
}

During every CRON run: Drupal will look for up to $max_entities number of entities. It will load every entity and iterate through them. For each $entity, the Status will be set and the Entity will be saved.
Note: Drupal Cron should be activated and running periodically. If it's not set you can find the docs here. I suggest using external triggers such as crontab or similar in the server.

Bonus

If you want to set up a Settings form for your module, I found a nice post talking about it.

If the actual $entity work is heavier than "Setting status to TRUE", then I suggest using QueueWorkers. You can find a beautiful blog post explaining them here.


